# Open source HTTP or HTTPS proxy

Tags: proxy, https

I want to log all HTTP requests made by the browser to a file, so I thought I can run a HTTP/S proxy locally and do this. However, the proxies at proxies.xhaus.com/ don't meet my needs - either no HTTPS support or no logging. Do anyone of you know of a proxy that can do both HTTPS and HTTP and allow me to log the browser traffic to a file?

Comment: this is not programming question but I'm interested why do you require open-source? in another question you complain that the only way to change some preference is to recompile the source code... so what's the point of searching for open-source program if you don't want to touch its source code?

Comment: If there is an easier way to get the logging to work, e.g. by changing a configuration parameter, I'd prefer that to recompiling the squid source code. I prefer open source since in the worst case, I can add some functionality if its missing. HTH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Squid was also my first thought given your description, but for development use you might prefer a more powerful intercepting proxy like:

- [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)
- [Paros Proxy](http://www.parosproxy.org/index.shtml)
- [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/suite/) (despite the name, my personal favorite)

Comment: Thanks. I set up squid, but will probably check these out if I get a chance.

Comment: I couldn't get squid to log the full request/response, so I tried using Paros Proxy, and it works like a charm. With a bit of hacking around, I could even change the source so that it logs the http messages by default.

Comment: This is no longer up to date. Only Squid is still open source.

Comment: Neither of these options are open source. Downvoted.

Answer (score 7):

[Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) can do that.

http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslBump